# WP8 - How to create and open a WebBrowser in Windows Phone 8 only through C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, browser

I am new to windows Phone development, so please excuse my ignorance.
I need to create and open a WebBrowser on a button click (button created on xaml page) in C# code. I have seen so many examples where the WebBrowser is created in XAML and Navigate is called in C#. But my requirement is to create a complete screen on button click.

Can anyone help me with this ? Any level of guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered simply switching to the Internet Explorer app with your URI when your button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head and assuming the main grid is named "LayoutRoot":

```
    private void btnOpenAndGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        web.Height = LayoutRoot.Height;
        web.Width = LayoutRoot.Width;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(web);
        web.Navigate(...);
    }
```

Edit: To control the hardware back button. Override OnBackKeyPress. And do something like this:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

        if (web.Visibility = Visibility.Visibile)
        {
            web.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks JonPall, I tried your suggestion, it works but it takes only the first grid of the layout. I need to open up as a new page, so that when i hit back button, it should go back to my main xaml page. any suggestions on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

JonPall's Answer is nice, and if you want to open you uri in IE, try this method:

using namespace : **Microsoft.Phone.Tasks**

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.URL = "http://yoururl.com";
task.Show();
```

Comment: thanks chris, but i was looking for something within app, so external browser won't suit the need.